# Kendo UI dropdowns are taking a lot of time to load data in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I am using Kendo UI with ASP.NET MVC. There are 6 dropdowns on the home page, taking a lot of time to load the data, nearly 45 seconds. Data is not large.

This is how all the dropdown are written:

```
@(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(model => model.ProductId)
  .Name("GreenProduct")
  .DataTextField("Name")
  .DataValueField("ProductId")
  .AutoBind(false)
  .DataSource(datasource => datasource
  .Read(read => read
       .Action("GetProductForProject", "Product")
       .Data("hierarchy.filterProduct")
       .Type(HttpVerbs.Post)
        )
       .ServerFiltering(true)
        )
  .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
  .Suggest(false)
  .Delay(0)
  .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%" })
  )
```

This is the loading screenshot:

[image]

I don't want to load data on dropdowns on page load and API's are also not calling on page load. I checked it by keeping breakpoint, but Process circle right side to the dropdowns keeps running. How can I fix this ?

Comment: I don't think it is anythink about Kendo. Check the execution time of action `GetProductForProject` of `Product` controller, better to check the exact query which is sent to server using tools like Firefox developer tools, and then test it either in browser or postman to see the server-side performance

Comment: @MDZand - What's happening in above dropdown, Data getting bind(API) on page load or when I click on it ? My intension is make API call when I click on Dropdown.

Comment: Yes check the calls after click. I guess results are not coming in reasonable time.

Comment: AutoBind false should be doing what you want (no bind and server call until opened) but clearly it isn't. I can't see anything wrong with your code. Does removing Filter, Suggest and Delay make any difference? Is there any javascript that runs after page load that interacts with these dropdowns in any way?

Comment: @NigelK - API calls are not happening on page load but the process circle on right side in the dropdowns keeps running for a long.

Comment: @MDZand - I checked APIs are not calling on page load. The delay because of dropdowns process circle keeps running for a long as showing in screenshot.